# How is this call to method resolved in Inheritance in java?

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

Why `doAction(A a)` will be selected in this situation?

**Can you advice some articles to read about method selection depending on argument type?**

```
class A { } 
class B extends A { } 
class D {
    void start(A a){ 
        doAction(a); 
    }
    void doAction(A a) { 
        System.out.println("A action"); 
    } 
    void doAction(B b) { 
        System.out.println("B action"); 
    } 
} 
public class Test { 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        new D().start(new B()); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that it's really a duplicate of that, as it's not asking how to select based on execution-time type. The answer is still relevant though...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why doAction(A) will be selected in this situation?

Because it's the only applicable method. Overload resolution is performed at *compile-time*, based on the *compile-time* type of the arguments.

The `doAction(B)` method isn't applicable, because there's no implicit conversion from `A` (the type of your argument) to `B` (the type of the parameter). You could cast the value to `B` like this:

```
doAction((B) a);
```

At that point both methods would be applicable, but overload resolution would pick `doAction(B b)` as being more *specific* than `doAction(A a)`. Of course, it will also fail if you pass in a reference which *isn't* to an instance of `B`.

You should read [JLS 15.12.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2) for the precise details of overload resolution.